# How do I distribute tasks to multiple celery workers in parallel?

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

> It seems every celery questions are like 5 years to 10 years old and
> utilizing old celery versions and design patterns

Using celery version 5.0.5

I have a celery task that queries the database and then performs some computations/calculations on each row of the rows returned by query

Issue is this task is taking several minutes to complete because of the thousands of rows returned from query so i am trying to distribute to multiple celery workers in parallel

```
@celery.task()
def send_sms(to, body):
    from twilio.rest import Client

    account_sid = os.environ["ACCOUNT_SID"]
    auth_token = os.environ["AUTH_TOKEN"]
    from_ = os.environ["NUMBER"]

    client = Client(
        account_sid,
        auth_token,
    )

    message = client.messages.create(
        to=to,
        from_=from_,
        body=body,
    )


@celery.task()
def notify_users():
    session = create_session()
    query = session.query(Rentals).filter(Rentals.enabled == True)
    today = datetime.now()
    for q in query:
        if q.returned_date is not None:
            if (today - q.returned_date).total_seconds() < q.rental_period:
                continue


        user = session.query(Users).filter(User.id == q.user_id).one()

        to = send_notification_get_to.get(q.notification_method)(user)
        body = f"sending email to {user.email}"

        send_sms.delay(to, body)
```

What will be the best way to distribute these tasks to multiple workers as opposed to letting one worker run it for several minutes which gets slower exponentially as the number of rows returned increase from a few thousands to tens of thousands

Comment: There is no direct answer to your question as it depends on the nature of work that this task performs. As it is a large DB query + processing of data, question is can you break it down and process only N rows by a single task (that could be an additional parameter to the task). Problem here is transactional processing. These smaller queries will be executed by different processes, so the queries can't be part of a single transaction, so depending on the job, it may be better to run it all at once as you already do.

Comment: why doesnt celery claimed to be a `distributed task queue` have native solution for this use-case? why? that is the part that baffles me...where is the `distributed` part to use for my use-case?

Comment: running it once is not scalable..what happens if i have millions of rows..it will take hours to complete...i want to be able to complete the task in less than 5 minutes at the very least...willing to throw many workers at it to get this result

Comment: Celery distributes EXECUTION. It is your job to write tasks to be good enough to be distributed around... There is no system that can do what you obviously want it to do - to break your tasks business logic down (no matter how complex it is) so it can distribute it.

Comment: in my example i showed exactly what i am trying to do...so not sure what you mean by depends on nature of work..did you read the code in the question? i want to send sms/text messages to users where the rentals is not due yet....that is pretty clear and it is ok to assume things in order to find solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same use case earlier, what I did was

I paginated the query (broke the records into smaller chunks) and each page was processed by a celery worker

You can also try using different worker pools like **gevent**, **eventlet** pools for better performance.

the code would look like this.

```
@celery.task()
def send_sms(to, body):
    from twilio.rest import Client

    account_sid = os.environ["ACCOUNT_SID"]
    auth_token = os.environ["AUTH_TOKEN"]
    from_ = os.environ["NUMBER"]

    client = Client(
        account_sid,
        auth_token,
    )

    message = client.messages.create(
        to=to,
        from_=from_,
        body=body,
    )


@celery.task()
def notify_range_of_users(num_chunks, skip):
    session = create_session()
    today = datetime.now()

    query = session.query(Rentals).filter(Rentals.enabled == True)

    paginated_query = query.limit(num_chunks).offset(skip * num_chunks)
    for q in paginated_query:

        if q.returned_date is not None:
            if (today - q.returned_date).total_seconds() < q.rental_period:
                continue

        user = session.query(Users).filter(User.id == q.user_id).one()

        to = send_notification_get_to.get(q.notification_method)(user)
        body = f"sending email to {user.email}"

        send_sms.delay(to, body)


@celery.task()
def notify_users():
    session = create_session()
    today = datetime.now()

    query = session.query(Rentals).filter(Rentals.enabled == True)
    total_rentals = query.count()
    # each chunk will contain, 100 rows/objects
    num_chunks = 100

    # find total number of chunks
    quo, remainder = divmod(total_rentals, num_chunks)
    # each job will contain a certain number of chunks
    jobs = quo

    if remainder:
        jobs = jobs + 1

    skip = 0
    for i in range(jobs):
        notify_range_of_users.delay(num_chunks, skip)

        # increment skip to go the next page
        skip = skip + 1
```

Comment: yeah splitting into smaller chunks was my next workaround if there is no native way to solve this...i would have thought celery should have this natively built..considering it is a very popular distributed task queue...the iron in `distributed` where i have to engineer the distributed part myself

Comment: can you please share how i will paginate and split things as i have mentioned in your answer? Will appreciate your help

Comment: will check it out in a bit...truly appreciate it...will update in a few

Comment: quick question...why are you calling the same query again twice? `query = session.query(Rentals).filter(Rentals.enabled == True)` in `notify_users()` and `notify_range_of_users(num_chunks, skip)`...the query can return different results after a second for example if called more than once..so not sure if that was intended or a mistake....will like to know...thanks again... **UPDATE:** might be best to call the query and store result in memory and then pass the result to the other function..that way query is ran once..let me know what you think

Comment: in `notify_users()` function I am calculating only the pages, in `notify_range_of_users()` the actual processing happens, like you mentioned the query could return different results, you should consider ordering by `id` or `created_at` time in the query :)

Comment: your solutions helps for sure..and sucks that celery does not natively support this...will accept as answer...found out splitting is only way for now at least

Comment: one other question..i noticed that celery workers take time to loop over even 100 rows...some take like 10 seconds on first run...is there any solution in python that can loop over sql rows faster? i may start looking into a library that can speed up looping over sql rows

not sure if you had this challenge also

Comment: I believe the issue could be with the database rather than python since you have mentioned that there are a lot of rows.

Comment: nopes not with database...database returns result fine..it is slow as snail python taking long to compute per ro

Comment: about to migrate my codebase from python to golang...python is truly crap when it comes to speed and performance